# What's wrong with my Ionic/Angular state inheritance?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and AngularJS so I'm struggling with (hopefully) something simple. I have these two states:

```
.state('menu', {
        url: '/mobile/beer',
        controller: 'beerCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'templates/beer-menu.html'
})
.state('detail', {
        url: '/mobile/beer/:id',
        controller: 'beerDetailCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'templates/beer.html',
        resolve: {
           beer: function($stateParams, beerService) {
              return beerService.findBeerById($stateParams.id) 
           }
        }
})
```

The 'menu' state fetches all beers from a server and hand the list over to 'beer-menu.html' that contains an ion-list to display the list. When the user selects a beer in the list, the 'detail' states steps in to display more details about the beer.

It's all working but I want to improve it a bit by using an abstract state:

```
.state('beer', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/mobile/beer'
    })
.state('beer.menu', {
        url: '',
        controller: 'beerCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'templates/beer-menu.html'
    })
.state('beer.detail', {
        url: '/:id',
        controller: 'beerDetailCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'templates/beer.html',
        resolve: {
           beer: function($stateParams, beerService) {
             return beerService.findBeerById($stateParams.id) 
           }
       }
})
```

It looks totally OK to me - esp because this is based on one of the 'Formulas' from the Ionic Framework website. Nevertheless the app stops working when I structure the states like that. I've tried to tweak it in various way but couldn't get it working. Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: same here. never worked for me correctly and i read a lot about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the UI-Router documentation you have to define also a *template for abstract* state 'beer':

> **Remember**: Abstract states still need their own `<ui-view/>` for their children to plug into. So if you are using an abstract state just to prepend a url, set resolves/data, or run an onEnter/Exit function, then you'll additionally need to set template: "`<ui-view/>`".

See:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Comment: Awesome - thank you Beaver - I'd overseen that detail. As I'm using Ionic, I had to replace <ui-view/> by <ion-nav-view/>. It's all working now - thank you :)